# C++ Builder ActiveX get property method overflow

Tags: delphi, c++builder, ole, activexobject

In C++ Builder XE7, I created a simple COM automation object:

1. File > New > ActiveX > ActiveX Library
2. File > New > ActiveX > Automation Object
3. Add new property MyProperty
4. Push 'Refresh implementation'

So, the wizard created declarations/implementations for get/set methods:

```
interface IMyObject: IDispatch
{
  [propget, id(0x000000CA)]
  HRESULT _stdcall MyProperty([out, retval] long* Value);
  [propput, id(0x000000CA)]
  HRESULT _stdcall MyProperty([in] long Value);
  };

STDMETHODIMP TMyObjectImpl::get_MyProperty(long* Value)
{
  try
  {

  }
  catch(Exception &e)
  {
    return Error(e.Message.c_str(), IID_IMyObject);
  }
  return S_OK;
}
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
...
```

In order to get the property value for automation clients, I inserted the code to assign the Property value to the Value referenced by the parameter:

```
STDMETHODIMP TMyObjectImpl::get_MyProperty(long* Value)
{
  try
  {
    *Value = MyProperty;
  }
  catch(Exception &e)
  {
    return Error(e.Message.c_str(), IID_IMyObject);
  }
  return S_OK;
}
```

Getting the property value in the client application, the server function TMyObjectImpl::get_MyProperty(long* Value) seems to run recursively until gets stack overflow.

Here is a simple client code:

```
Variant Object;
double N;
V = Variant::CreateObject("MyProject.MyObject");
N = V.OlePropertyGet("MyProperty");
```

What I am doing wrong in this assignment?

```
*Value = MyProperty;
```

Comment: By accessing `MyProperty` the getter method (`get_MyProperty`) defined for the property is called. Obviously, if you do this from within `get_MyProperty` you are causing endless recursion. Normally you would declare a private field used to store the value of your property and write your getter method to return the value of this private field.

Comment: So, I have to define a field in order to store the property data, instead the property itself. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```cpp
STDMETHODIMP TMyObjectImpl::get_MyProperty(long* Value)
{
  try
  {
    *Value = MyProperty;
  }
  catch(Exception &e)
  {
    return Error(e.Message.c_str(), IID_IMyObject);
  }
  return S_OK;
}
```

Reading `MyProperty` is implemented by a call to `get_MyProperty`. Hence the unterminated recursion.

You need to implement `get_MyProperty` by returning a value obtained by some other means. For instance, you might return a constant value:

```
*Value = 42;
```

Or you might return a value stored in a member field:

```
*Value = myPropertyValue;
```

where `myPropertyValue` is a member field of your class.